# Getting correct dimensions of custom view

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I am trying to draw a cross hair inside a custom view,

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus)
{   super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
    top=this.getTop()+(this.getTop()/10);
    bottom=this.getBottom()-(this.getBottom()/10);
    left=this.getLeft()+(this.getLeft()/10);
    right=this.getRight()-(this.getRight()/10);
    Log.e("graph",getTop()+":"+top+","+this.getBottom()+":"+bottom+","+this.getLeft()+":"+left+","+this.getRight()+":"+right);
}
```

I am using this code to get the top,bottom,left and right coordinates of view and adjusting tenth part as padding.

inside onDraw method,

```
    canvas.drawLine(left, (bottom - top) / 2, right, (bottom - top) / 2, paint);
    canvas.drawLine((right-left)/2,top,(right-left)/2,bottom,paint);
```

these two methods to draw a line which is horizontally centered and vertically centered. I am getting this drawing on my phone's screen.

The [image]

I want to have horizontal centered and vertically centered line, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The top, bottom, left, and right properties don't describe the dimensions of the view.  They describe the position of the view within its container.

Instead, use getWidth() and getHeight() on the view object instead to find the dimensions and draw using that information.

Comment: In http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html, it is written "For instance, calling getRight() is similar to the following computation: getLeft() + getWidth()" so I don't thisnk it would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

top, bottom, are all coordinates relative to the position of the view in ist container,
I think you need to draw the line like:

```
canvas.drawLine(this.getLeft(), (this.getTop() + this.getBottom())/2, this.getRight(), (this.getTop() + this.getBottom())/2, paint);
canvas.drawLine((this.getLeft()+this.getRight())/2, this.getTop(), (this.getLeft()+this.getRight())/2, this.getBottom(), paint);
```